# How can is 'tslib' over 'typecrypt' in the number of downloads?

Tags: typescript, npm, tslib

'tslib' is a 'typescript' library, how can it be downloaded more times than 'typescripts'?

- If 'typescript' is not used, 'tslib' cannot be used.
- Using a 'typescript' does not mean that 'tslib' is a must.
  Therefore I think the number of downloads of 'typescript' >= 'tslib' is reasonable reasoning, but I don't understand.

[npm trends](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rW128.png)

I asked chatgpt, but I couldn't get the right answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While it might initially seem surprising that 'tslib', a TypeScript library, has more downloads than TypeScript itself, this can be explained by understanding the different roles and usage patterns of 'tslib' and TypeScript in software development:

1. **Widespread Dependency and Production Build Inclusion**: 'tslib' is not only a fundamental dependency for numerous libraries and projects but is also often included in production builds. This dual role means that 'tslib' is downloaded both during development and as part of the final deployment of many projects, contributing to its higher download count.
2. **Frequent Downloads in Multi-Dependency Projects**: Projects using TypeScript frequently have several dependencies that require 'tslib'. Each dependency's installation results in a separate download of 'tslib', increasing its overall download frequency. TypeScript, typically a development-only dependency, is installed less often, usually once per project.
3. **Diverse Version Requirements**: Various projects and libraries may need different versions of 'tslib', leading to repeated downloads in different versions. TypeScript, while used across these projects, often maintains more consistent versioning, leading to fewer downloads over time.

The higher download count for 'tslib' compared to TypeScript can be attributed to its role as a common dependency in numerous projects, its repeated downloads in projects with multiple dependencies, and the diverse version requirements across different projects. This phenomenon highlights the intricate nature of package dependencies and usage in the npm ecosystem.

Comment: So is it correct that 'tslib' should be added to the dependencies, unlike 'typescript' that should be added to the devdependencies?

Comment: @김첨지 The necessity to include or exclude certain components in the `dependencies` of your application largely varies based on the specific scenario in which the app is being deployed and the particular features utilized within the application. In some instances, it may be feasible to omit them from the `dependencies`, while in other scenarios, this may not be possible.

Comment: @김첨지  For instance, if you are creating a library in which the outcome is only compiled to the JS at the end, you can omit it from the `dependencies`.

Comment: Then, in the case of a library that is compiled into TS at the end, you need it, right?

Comment: @김첨지 Yeah, that is correct.

Answer (score 2):

TypeScript is used in development and tslib is used in production builds as well - so you are likely to have one download for TypeScript (the one you're using) but many for tslib (one for every dependency written in TypeScript).

Comment: So is it correct that 'tslib' should be added to the dependencies, unlike 'typescript' that should be added to the devdependencies?

Comment: correct, that is